# Change a variable value inside a Jquery .filter() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, global-variables

I have a table which has id 'myTable'. Now there is a textbox in which I write down the item name to find whether it exists in the myTable cell or not. To do this I have written the following code -

```
var retval=0;   
var search = $("#searchitem").val().trim();
$("table#myTable tr td").filter(function() {
    if($(this).text() == search){retval=1;alert('Same item found');}
else{retval=0;}
});
```

The problem is that, when it finds the same item in the table cell it shows the alertbox. But the value of my variable `retval` never changes. It always shows `0`. How can I solve it?

Comment: can you please put your html code or create a fiddle?

Comment: Where do you need to see retval? Is it in scope there?

Comment: Probably in one iteration its making retval=1 and in the next resetting it back to 0, put an alert in else block and then debug.

Comment: use `console.log` instead of alerts. It's much easier to see what's happening than getting stupid boxes popping up everywhere.

Comment: What are you using `retval` *for*? I think there's probably a better solution to whatever problem you're facing than the one you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to accomplish could be done by using :contains() selector, like this:

```
var search = $("#searchitem").val().trim();
var retval = $("table#myTable tr td:contains('"+search+"'") ? 1 : 0;
```

I haven't tested it but I'm almost sure it works. It's a much more cleaner approach and surely more readable.

**jQuery :contains() docs:** http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

please try `return false` like this

```
var retval=0;   
var search = $("#searchitem").val().trim();
$("table#myTable tr td").filter(function() {
    if($(this).text() == search){
        retval=1;
        alert('Same item found');
        return false;
    }else{
        retval=0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change the variable value only if found , because you assign the variable to **0** at the beginning.

```
var retval=0;   
var search = $("#searchitem").val().trim();
$("table#myTable tr td").filter(function() {
    if($(this).text() == search){
        retval=1;
        alert('Same item found');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var search = $("#searchitem").val().trim();
var filteredData = $("table#myTable tr td").filter(function(element, index) 
{
    return $(element).text() == search;
});
```

now this code return array of TD elements which satisfy the condition.